# How to update PSQL database when array is Javascript is updated?

Tags: php, javascript, database, arrays, psql

I am trying to combine PHP and Javascript, so that I get my data from the db in psql. So far, I am able to obtain the column I need, and set an array equal to this data. And then I am equating a js array to this array. This can be seen in the following code:

```
<?php

   // attempt a connection
 $dbh = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=db user=postgres");
 if (!$dbh) {
     die("Error in connection: " . pg_last_error());
 }       

 // execute query
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM dataset";
 $result = pg_query($dbh, $sql);
 if (!$result) {
     die("Error in SQL query: " . pg_last_error());
 }       

 $arr = pg_fetch_all_columns($result, 1);

 pg_free_result($result);       

 // close connection
 pg_close($dbh);

?>
```

And here's the js part.

```
var data = <?php echo json_encode($arr); ?>;
```

I have a function, which adds a data point to the array. I can add it to "data" array in js, but how do I make it so that it reflects in the db?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: you use an ajax call to signal to the server that an update's been made.

Comment: @MarcB I am really new to this, could you expand a little on this? Thanks.